# 2 fundamental frequencies observed on a wire?

Tags: waves, frequency, string

In an A-Level Physics Practical, we investigated fundamental standing waves on a wire using the setup in the attached diagram. Our signal generator had a scale dial, allowing it to vary between x1, x10, etc. frequencies. We measured these frequencies using an attached PicoScope. Investigating waves with a wavelength of 1-0.6m we got values between 5-15Hz, but upon reaching 0.5m we needed to use the scalar dial on x10. For 0.5m we got a frequency of 20Hz. This seemed odd, so I repeated 1m-0.6m using the scalar dial on x10. This time I got values of 20-40Hz! All these values were read from the PicoScope software, so this was not an issue with the signal generator, and this was consistent across my class between people who used x10 and people who used x1.

How is it possible that we found 2 fundamental frequencies? The only solution I can think of is that the wave speed changed but how would this happen?

[image: Practical Equipment]

Comment: How did you prescribe the forcing/initial condition?

Comment: From your measured tensions and mass per unit length of the wire what were your predicted wavelengths and/or frequencies? How was the picoscope connected and used to measure the frequency?

Comment: And what do you mean by "upon reaching 0.5 m"? How do you get these values?

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

The speed of propagation of perturbations didn't change. The modes (with their proper frequency) you're looking at, or the modes you're forcing if you changed your experimental set-up, probably did.

Both the forced and the free evolution of a elastic wire, or a linear mechanical system in general, can be written as a **superposition of its natural modes**, namely its eigenvectors, each one evolving in time (with frequency and damping - for stable systems - of the oscillations) in a way determined by the corresponding eigenvalue.

**A continuous media, has an infinite number of natural frequencies, and modes**, namely the eigensolutions, while we can usually observe only those one that are:

- excited by external forces or initial conditions (that can be interpreted as the result of an impulsive force);
- not strongly damped, usually those one close to a resonance, or at lower frequencies, since physical systems usually behave as low-pass filters far away from resonances.

For a wire, the frequencies $\omega_n$ are related with the wave-number $k_n$ allowed by the boundary conditions, and are usually a function of the length of the wire $\ell$, the tension $T_0$ and the mass per unit length $m$, with a functional dependence

$\omega_n = \sqrt{\dfrac{T_0}{m}} \ k_n(\ell, \text{b.c.})$

In your set-up the allowed wave-numbers should be $k_n = \dfrac{n \pi}{ \ell}$, and the frequencies $\omega_n = \dfrac{n \pi}{\ell} \sqrt{\dfrac{T_0}{m}}$. **This result is consistent with you measurements of 2 frequencies, with $\omega_2 = 2 \omega_1$**. If you provide us some details of the experimental apparatus, namely:

- the length $\ell$ of the wire, or the distance between the two bridges,
- the tension $T_0$ or, alternatively, the mass $m$ of your weights from we could approximately find $T_0 = m g$, assuming no (or negligible) vertical displacement of the mass;
- the mass $m$ per unit length of the wire;
  we could test if this simple formula agrees with your experimental measurements.

### Detailed answer

A 1D model of a wire with tension $T_0$ as pre-stress, can be used to write the governing equation for bending as

$m \ddot{w}(x,t) - T_0 w''(x,t) = f(x,t)\qquad$ for $x \in [0,\ell]$

being $m$ the mass per unit length of the wire, $T_0$ the tension in the wire, $f(x,t)$ the lateral force per unit length applied to the wire, $w(x,t)$ the lateral displacement of the points of the wire w.r.t. to the straight configuration. Here I use $\dot{w} = \partial_{t} w$ and $w' = \partial_x w$.

The indefinite equilibrium equation must be provided with boundary conditions and initial conditions.

The free evolution of the system can be decomposed as waves with frequencies that are determined by the boundary conditions. Here I assume constrained ends so that $w(0,t) = 0$ and $w(\ell,t) = 0$.

The governing equation is nothing more than a wave equation for $w(x,t)$ with speed of perturbances $c^2 = \frac{T_0}{m}$.

Focusing on the homogeneous equation governing the free evolution of the system, we can approach the problem in several different ways:

- assuming solution with as superposition of traveling waves, in the form $w(x,t) = W e^{i(\omega t + k t)}$;
- writing the homogeneous equation separating the variables, namely writing $w(x,t)$ as the product of a function of time and a function of space only, $w(x,t) = f(x)g(t)$,

  $\dfrac{m}{T_0}\ddot{w} -  w'' = 0 $$\qquad \rightarrow \qquad $
  $\dfrac{m}{T_0} \dfrac{\ddot{g}}{g} = \dfrac{f''}{f} = C \quad \text{const}$,

  being $C$ constant since the two terms on the left must be equal despite being function of different independent variables.

  In order to have feasible solutions, $C = - k^2$ must be negative.
  The solutions we get are:

  - $f(x) = A \cos(k x) + B \sin(k x)$, with boundary conditions $w(0,t) = w(\ell,t) = 0$ enforcing $A = 0$ and $k \ell = n \pi$, in order to have $\sin(k \ell) = 0$. So, we have found the possible values of $k$, and the form of the space functions $f(x)$

    $k_n = n \dfrac{\pi}{\ell} $
    $f_n(x) = B \sin(k_n x) = B \sin \left( \dfrac{n \pi x}{\ell}\right)$
  - $g_n(t) = a \cos( c k_n t) + b \sin( c k_n t)$, and thus the natural frequency of the $n^{th}$ mode reads

    $\omega_n = c k_n = n \dfrac{\pi}{\ell}\sqrt{\dfrac{T_0}{m}}$

  Eventually the solution can be written as the superposition of the solutions $w_n(x,t) = f_n(x) g_n(t)$, namely

  $w(x,t) = \displaystyle \sum_{n} \left[ a_n \cos\left(n\dfrac{\pi}{\ell} \sqrt{\dfrac{T_0}{m}} t \right) + b_n \sin \left(n\dfrac{\pi}{\ell} \sqrt{\dfrac{T_0}{m}} t \right) \right] \sin \left(n\dfrac{\pi}{\ell}x \right)$,

  being $a_n$, $b_n$ the constants to be found with the initial conditions.